# Azure AD B2C: Is it possible to achieve username-password based login alongside Single-Sign-On through a custom app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, saml

So I recently started exploring Azure Identity Platform for this user authorization use case I'm trying to implement. After a bit of research I came across using Graph API and creating ROPC flows to handle SingUp and Login via REST API from my application. My requirement is also to allow users to use login credentials from another app (I'm not sure yet if it implements a SAML based Identity Provider method) to use services in my application. This is a typical SSO requirement, but I'm not sure if it is possible to implement alongside username-password based authentication using Azure AD B2C.

I would appreciate any leads. Thank you.

Edit: To be more precise, I am working with Java-Spring. The demo application mentioned in Azure AD documentation (Woodgrove groceries) is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. A quick google search for the same provides me with github repos with sample code that uses .Net I believe. Are there any Java sample codes that demonstrate the same?

Answer (score 0):

ROPC [does not support SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-aad-b2c-considerations#resource-owner-password-credentials-ropc) if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm pretty much clear about this point now, that ROPC allows us to perform certain operations using REST API calls. My question was, suppose I implement a basic signUp flow using ROPC. Later on, can I also allow my application to use SSO through some other methods? I want to support both flows, but I will be implementing it separately.

Comment: Instead of using the term SSO, describe what you actually mean, because the answer stated already that ROPC does not allow for SSO against another sign in flow/policy. What “other methods” are you referring to? Maybe describe overall your goal.

Comment: Hi @JasSuri, I have edited my question to be more elaborate. What I am trying to achieve is an authentication model similar to the demo application that is given in the Azure AD documentation. That is, users can either login using email/phone and password or by using credentials from another app that has OpenId end points. I believe I got the answer to the question "Can I?", as the given demo already addressed this using .Net. I'm not sure how I would implement this using Java-Spring boot.